# Python 3 KeyboardInterrupt error

Tags: python-3.x, ctrl, keyboardinterrupt

I have noticed that on any python 3 program no matter how basic it is if you press CTRL c it will crash the program for example:

```
test=input("Say hello")
if test=="hello":
    print("Hello!")
else:
    print("I don't know what to reply I am a basic program without meaning :(")
```

If you press CTRL c the error will be KeyboardInterrupt is there anyway of stopping this from crashing the program?

The reason I want to do this is because I like to make my programs error proof, and whenever I want to paste something into the input and I accidentally press CTRL c I have to go through my program again..Which is just very annoying.

Comment: That's the whole point of Ctrl + C. It's a hotkey to exit out of whatever program you're running.

Comment: really? Never knew that that was a thing in python

Comment: Not just Python, anything you run in the command line. It's been that way since early UNIX systems.

Comment: Oh im new to coding im only 14 don't even know what UNIX systems are but I guess that makes sense

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Control-C` will raise a `KeyboardInterrupt` no matter how much you don't want it to. However, you can pretty easily handle the error, for example, if you wanted to require the user to hit control-c twice in order to quit while getting input you could do something like:

```
def user_input(prompt):
    try:
        return input(prompt)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("press control-c again to quit")
    return input(prompt) #let it raise if it happens again
```

Or to force the user to enter something no matter how many times they use `Control-C` you could do something like:

```
def upset_users_while_getting_input(prompt):
    while True: # broken by return
        try:
            return input(prompt)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("you are not allowed to quit right now")
```

Although I would not recommend the second since someone who uses the shortcut would quickly get annoyed at your program.

Comment: Gratz to 10k :-)

Comment: As a side note, if you have a Mac **copy is command-c** and _KeyboardInterupt is control-c_ so I never get this issue when copying stuff. ;P

Answer (score 0):

Also, in your program, if someone inputs "Hello", it would not reply hello back as the first letter is capital, so you can use:

```
if test.isupper == True:
  print("Hello!")
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.